# I want to filter my products with attributes

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, customization, permalinks

I have ebook store, where all the books are listed, everything is done.. 
In products, publisher and author added as a custom attributes. Now I want to filter the products on the basis of attributes...,

Need:

Just need to set its links, because I create a publisher page in which all the book publishers name fetched from databse with the help of below code that I cretae for filter the producs, next is I just want that when somebody click on the publisher name it shows all the books of that publisher, all is done but only need to add a link of every publisher

Code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
global $product;
    $attr = get_post_meta($product->id, '_product_attributes', true);  
$attr_label = $attr['publisher'];
$m = $attr_label["value"];
$d[$m] = "1";
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
ksort($d);

 echo "<ul>";
  foreach($d as $index=>$val){
      echo "<li><a href=''>".$index."</a></li>";
 }
 echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

As per what I understood from your question, you want two things - 
Listing of all publisher
Listing of all books of a particular publisher.

Here is code for both.

**Listing of all publisher**

```
$terms = get_terms( 'pa_publisher' );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $each_term) {
    echo '<li>'.$each_term->name.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**Listing of all books of a particular publisher**

```
 $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_publisher',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'matt' // name of publisher
              )
           )
       );

$products = get_posts( $args );
echo '<ul>';
foreach($products as $each_product) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$each_product->guid.'" >'.$each_product->post_title.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Where did the `pa_publisher` taxonomy come from? I'm not sure that is built into WordPress or WooCommerce.

Comment: When you create attribute in woocommerce, it is stored as taxonomy with prefix pa_ . Stands for product attribute.

Comment: Ah, the more you know, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: List of the publisher is already done, just need to fix the link ....??